# Converting SQL Query to Databricks SQL

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-community-edition

I have a query that I need to convert to Databricks SQL or run against a table in a Databrick environment but failing even though it works very well against tables SQL Server. The tables and query can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4aade2a388ffa21356f1581c4212b540)

The query to convert or run in Databricks environment is:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT EventID
         , EventName
         , EventStartDateTime
         , IIF(EventEndDateTime = '',GETUTCDATE(),EventEndDateTime) 
           AS EventEndDateTime
     FROM EventLog

     UNION ALL

     SELECT EventID
          , EventName
          , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , 
             EventStartDateTime)), 0) AS EventStartDateTime
          , EventEndDateTime
     FROM CTE 
     WHERE  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , 
     EventStartDateTime)), 0)  <= EventEndDateTime
  )
```

And then selecting from the CTE like so:

```
SELECT EventID
     , EventName
     , YEAR(EventStartDateTime)
     , DATENAME(MONTH,EventStartDateTime)
     , DATEDIFF(SECOND, EventStartDateTime, n_EventStartDateTime) / 
         3600.0
 FROM (
   SELECT EventID
        , EventName
        , EventStartDateTime
        , LEAD(EventStartDateTime,1,EventEndDateTime) 
          OVER(PARTITION BY EventID,EventName ORDER BY 
           EventStartDateTime) n_EventStartDateTime
   FROM CTE
  ) t1
      OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

I equally noticed that

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , 
          EventStartDateTime)), 0) AS EventStartDateTime
```

and

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, EventStartDateTime, n_EventStartDateTime) / 3600.0
```

are not working in databricks environment.

I sincerely appreciate your help on this

Comment: hi @UpwardD, you can directly use same code by adding `spark.sql(""" your sql query """)` .please refer this https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-spark-2nd/9781492050032/ch04.html

Comment: Thanks. I am getting errors. Do I need to import any file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you found, the particular codes should be modified as follows:

**SQL Server Version:**

```sql
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(month , 1 , 
          EventStartDateTime)), 0) AS EventStartDateTime
```

**Databricks Version:**

```sql
add_months('1900-01-01', months_between(add_months(EventStartDateTime, 1), '1900-01-01'))
```

**SQL Server Version:**

```sql
DATEDIFF(SECOND, EventStartDateTime, n_EventStartDateTime) / 3600.0
```

**Databricks Version:**

```sql
datediff(EventStartDateTime, n_EventStartDateTime) * 24
```

Read [more](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#date-timestamp-and-interval-functions) about Databricks date function. Note that some functions are just released after particular Databricks SQL endpoint versions which may not be available yet.

Comment: Hi @PhuriChal. months('1900-01-01', months_between(add_months(EventStartDateTime, 1), '1900-01-01')) throws errors.............

Comment: Can you please share the error message?